# Issues with maven compiler

Tags: maven, grails, maven-compiler-plugin, grails-maven, grails-2.4

I am trying to use jetty plugin for a grails project. I am currently using jdk 1.6.0_45. It seems that the jre version used by jdk 1.6 is a little old one for jetty plugin and it generates the following error.

```
Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/plus/webapp/EnvConfiguration : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

To resolve this error I have added a code in the pom.xml to use java source 1.7. The code is something like this.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But still I continue to get the same error. Can any body please help me out.

I am posting my entire pom.xml and the error that I am getting

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>grails-mongo-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>grails-app</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>grails-mongo-demo</name>
    <description>grails-mongo-demo</description>
    <properties>
        <grails.version>2.4.2</grails.version>
        <h2.version>1.3.170</h2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-test</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${grails.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7-groovy-2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-datastore-test-support</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-grails-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>scaffolding</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>asset-pipeline</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>webxml</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <type>zip</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement />
        <plugins>
            <!-- Disables the Maven surefire plugin for Grails applications, as we have our own test runner -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>surefire-it</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>plugins</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*</include>
                            </includes>
                            <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <grailsVersion>${grails.version}</grailsVersion>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>grails</id>
            <name>grails</name>
            <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/core</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>grails-plugins</id>
            <name>grails-plugins</name>
            <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tools</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>java.vendor</name>
                    <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <version>${java.version}</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

**Error**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building grails-mongo-demo 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ grails-mongo-demo ---
[INFO] Deleting /mnt/data/Work/Tutorials/Practice/grails/grails-mongo-demo/target
[INFO] Deleting /mnt/data/Work/Tutorials/Practice/grails/grails-mongo-demo/plugins (includes = [**/*], excludes = [])
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3:clean (default-clean) @ grails-mongo-demo ---
4 Sep, 2014 6:28:00 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
4 Sep, 2014 6:28:00 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
|Loading Grails 2.4.2
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
.
|Environment set to development
....................
|Application cleaned.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3:validate (default-validate) @ grails-mongo-demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3:init (default-init) @ grails-mongo-demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3:config-directories (default-config-directories) @ grails-mongo-demo ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3:maven-compile (default-maven-compile) @ grails-mongo-demo ---
4 Sep, 2014 6:28:32 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
4 Sep, 2014 6:28:32 PM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-all] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
|Loading Grails 2.4.2
|Configuring classpath
|Running pre-compiled script
.
|Environment set to development
......
|Installing zip jetty-3.0.0.zip...
...
|Installed plugin jetty-3.0.0
.............
|Installing zip webxml-1.4.1.zip...
...
|Installed plugin webxml-1.4.1
.............
|Installing zip asset-pipeline-1.8.11.zip...
...
|Installed plugin asset-pipeline-1.8.11
..................
|Installing zip cache-1.1.7.zip...
...
|Installed plugin cache-1.1.7
..............
|Installing zip scaffolding-2.1.2.zip...
...
|Installed plugin scaffolding-2.1.2
..............
|Installing zip jquery-1.11.1.zip...
...
|Installed plugin jquery-1.11.1
..............
|Installing zip mongodb-3.0.2.zip...
...
|Installed plugin mongodb-3.0.2
...................
|Compiling 87 source files
.Error 
|
Fatal error during compilation org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jetty/plus/webapp/EnvConfiguration : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 47.500 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-04T18:28:42+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/102M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.grails:grails-maven-plugin:2.4.3:maven-compile (default-maven-compile) on project grails-mongo-demo: Forked Grails VM exited with error -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Why not use `BuildConfig.groovy` instead of `pom.xml`?

Comment: I want to migrate the code to maven, that is the requirement. I really cannot revert to using BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: The problem is that you are using a jdk 1.6 cause the jar file has been compiled with Java 7 which the message `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` exactly describes. So you have to use at least Java 7 to work with such artifacts. No relationship to Maven itself.

Comment: I understand the cause of the error. I have mentioned in the pom.xml to use jdk 7 in the maven compiler plugin. I fail to understand, why it is still using jdk 6.

Comment: what does java -version return - if this is still 6 maybe worth pointing environment java settings to 7 too..

Comment: Hi Vahid, java -version returns 1.6.0_45. The problem is that I need to use jdk7 for this project alone. I don't want to change the settings for other projects. Is there a way to specify java7 settings for this project alone.

Comment: if you dont have jdk7 on your machine, how will maven use it?